# jquery apply context menu on all children

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I am using a jquery context menu plugin (http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/) which works fine but I want to work for all children of a selector currently I have the below but it only applies to divs with class area and I need it to apply on div's with class area and all its children.

```
$('#container-area .area').contextMenu()
```

Any ideas on wildcard jquery selectors tried * with no luck

Lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, using `.andSelf()` ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/)):

```
$('#container-area .area').children("div").andSelf().contextMenu();
```

Comment: what if the children aren't all div's?

Comment: @monkeylee - Just remove the `"div"` part and make it `.children()` to get all children if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#container-area .area').contextMenu().find('*').contextMenu()
```